# Xpad crashes after clicking on "show desktop"

Tags: 13.10, notes, stickynotes

This question is about Xpad on Ubuntu 13.10.

I can start the application and write a note. If I click on another application, the note disappears and it re-appears if I click again on Xpad on the launcher. So far so good.

However, when I click on the "show desktop" button on the launcher Xpad crashes, that is, if I click again on Xpad on the launcher nothing happens. Right click + quit works. After re-starting Xpad it works again fine except that the old note has disappeared.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try v4.2 of Xpad, which has a lot of [bugfixes and some new functionality](https://launchpad.net/xpad/trunk/4.2). Unfortunately it is not available through the Ubuntu repositories yet, but if you have enough courage you can try to download, compile and install it yourself.

You can find the latest version here:
https://launchpad.net/xpad

Does this help you?